# What is the command to speed up processors ?

Tags: linux, debian

I get from other that I have 2 threads and that I could speed up processor execution time to 200%. 
I don't know the command. Could someone point me to some site ? Or just type it in here ? 
I am trying to do this on debian stretch 9.1.

[image]

Comment: Unless you have a specific problem or a specific command that has optional multithreading support (like ffmpeg when converting videos), this just happens automatically and you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Our PHP program is using around 100% of our processor time and we believe there are multiple threads open to the database. 
Isn't this a use case for speeding up the processors ?

Comment: No, you need to speak to the developers and advice them of the issue. You should always look at optimizing the software before optimizing/scaling the hardware.

Comment: Thanks Raman for the response. They have explained to me that there is no other way and I trust them. So this is the solution that we want to follow.

Comment: Screenshots are evil. Use textual copy-paste, if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, you cannot, I think, increase processor performance for your application. Your processor is scaled by the system, more demanding tasks will cause the CPU to rev up, less demanding task will not; this saves electrical power.

You can scale the CPU frequency manually, set the minimum frequency to, say 3000 Mhz, but that should not speed up your program because I am sure I/O is the bottleneck, that's why your CPU did not rev up.

Now, it might be a bug ...

You can do it manually:

```
cpupower frequency-set -u 3000
```

But watch out, it might have rev'ed down because of temperature issues and you might fry your CPU.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling

DISCLAIMER: You should not do it, imho. I am not responsible for the results of running that command ;-).